# Why does this function show an array of an array instead of just an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

```
use warnings;
use strict;

testfunc();
sub testfunc {
    my @first_pin_name_list=qw(
        VDD2_DDR2_S2_4
        VDD1_DDR2_S2_2
    );

    my @second_pin_name_list=qw(
        VDD2_DDR2_S2_4
        VDD1_DDR2_S2_2
    );
    my @expected_list =qw(
        VDD1_DDR0_S2_[2:1]
        VDD2_DDR0_S2_[5:1]
    );

    my @listoftests = ( 
        {INPUT_LIST => \@first_pin_name_list,OUTPUT_LIST => \@expected_list,OK_2_FAIL=> 0}, 
        {INPUT_LIST => \@second_pin_name_list,OUTPUT_LIST => \@expected_list,OK_2_FAIL => 1}

    );  

    print @expected_list;

    # should show an array but instead debugger shows an array of an array
    my @listtotest = $listoftests[0] -> {INPUT_LIST};
    print "hello";
    return @listoftests;
}
```

The debugger shows `@listtotest` containing an array of an array, but I want to see just an array with elements. How can I change my code to show just an array of elements?

Comment: I'm guessing the debugger is showing you `\@listtotest`, so that's the top level reference.  Others, it would treat each element separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't showing us what the debugger is showing you, but there is no array of arrays.

`$listoftests[0]->{INPUT_LIST}` is a reference to an array, @first_pin_name_list.
If you want to assign the elements in that array to `@listtotest`, you need to dereference it:

```
my @listtotest = $listoftests[0]->{INPUT_LIST}->@*;
```

or on older perls:

```
my @listtotest = @{ $listoftests[0]->{INPUT_LIST} };
```

Comment: apologies how can I add pictures on SO? Id like to know for future reference. Ill try this out. this may solve my problems.

Comment: can't you copy and paste from the debugger?  though I've seen pictures, I have no idea how and find pictures not very useful

Comment: ah ok. I can copy from the debugger, just thought it would not look clean on here.

Comment: Here is help on making things look clean here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help